# WPF : Move control c# code to change position from location to another

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

how can move (change position) label from position to another using **wpf** **

> animation

** in specify event such click using ***c# code not trigger*** ??

```
 using System.windows.media.animation;
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" Canvas.Left="201" Canvas.Top="116" x:Name="Button"/>

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var pointAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = Canvas.GetLeft(Button),
            To = Canvas.GetLeft(Button) + 200,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(pointAnimation, Button);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(pointAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
        storyboard.Children.Add(pointAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```